# My graphics card does not have CUDA 9.2, what is this?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, cuda

I'm trying to run a graphics editing program on my PC. It tells me I need to have CUDA 9.2 for the graphics card - I'm running an NVIDIA GeForce 210, although I may update this for video editing on this PC. Can I use CUDA 9.2 with this model of card? I'm a little confused what the difference between this and the driver is.

Can someone tell me what i need to do in order to update my driver etc. to use CUDA 9.2 and if it's not possible, how do I know what to look for in a new graphics card?

Comment: I think the 210 is the absolute lowest power, bottom of the range GPU NVidia make. It's nowhere near the list for CUDA capability - see https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: Your hardware does not support CUDA 9.2.  As for what to look for in a new GPU, you should select the GPU, based on your CUDA needs.  Hardware recomendations are specifically out of scope.